# R Language - Rolling averages across columns

Tags: r

I am trying to take a 3 game rolling average of some NFL data across columns, here is the data and resultant data frame:

data:

```
Player <- c("Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4", "Player5")
Week1 <- c(10, 5, 6, 8, 7)
Week2 <- c(12, 9, 4, 2, 8)
Week3 <- c(4, 5, 4, 3, 12)
Week4 <- c(15, 7, 12, NA, 5)
Week5 <- c(NA, 5, 8, 11, 6)
q <- data.frame(Player, Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5)
```

data frame:

```
   Player Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 Week5
1 Player1    10    12     4    15    NA
2 Player2     5     9     5     7     5
3 Player3     6     4     4    12     8
4 Player4     8     2     3    NA    11
5 Player5     7     8    12     5     6
```

So what I want to do is take 3 game rolling averages across the weeks, starting with week 1.  So for the players it would average Week1, Week2, Week3 and give me the value in a new column, then it would average Week2, Week3, Week4, and give me that value in a new column, etc...

In this case the new data frame should look like this:

```
   Player Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 Week5    Avg1    Avg2    Avg3
1 Player1    10    12     4    15    NA     8.7    10.3     NA
2 Player2     5     9     5     7     5     6.3     7.0     5.7
3 Player3     6     4     4    12     8     4.7     6.7     8.0
4 Player4     8     2     3    NA    11     4.3     4.3     5.3
5 Player5     7     8    12     5     6     9.0     8.3     7.7
```

Please notice that for Player4 in Week4 there was an NA that was disregarded...that would be a week the player didn't play for some reason, so I use the previous two games and the game after it for Avg3.

I need these new columns as I am going to be running a regression to see if the average of the 3 predicts the next value.  Everything I can find about this has the rolling average down a single column, but I am very inexperienced, so any help with data formatting for a problem like this is appreciated.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rollmean` from the `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(q[-1], 1, function(x) rollmean(x, 3))))


#       Week2     Week3    Week4
#[1,] 8.666667 10.333333       NA
#[2,] 6.333333  7.000000 5.666667
#[3,] 4.666667  6.666667 8.000000
#[4,] 4.333333        NA       NA
#[5,] 9.000000  8.333333 7.666667
```

Finally, to get a combined dataframe,

```
cbind(q, t(apply(q[-1], 1, function(x) rollmean(x, 3))))

#   Player Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 Week5    Week2     Week3    Week4
#1 Player1    10    12     4    15    NA 8.666667 10.333333       NA
#2 Player2     5     9     5     7     5 6.333333  7.000000 5.666667
#3 Player3     6     4     4    12     8 4.666667  6.666667 8.000000
#4 Player4     8     2     3    NA    11 4.333333        NA       NA
#5 Player5     7     8    12     5     6 9.000000  8.333333 7.666667
```

If you are specific about the column names, you can always change it by

```
temp <- t(apply(q[-1], 1, function(x) rollmean(x, 3)))
colnames(temp) <- c("avg1", "avg2", "avg3")
```

and then use `cbind` on `temp`

**EDIT**

To answer few of the OP's questions -

If you have more than one column to remove at the start, you can just select/deselect the columns with their index numbers

For example,

To deselect first two columns, you can use `q[-c(1:2)]` which is equal to `q[3:7]` which gives it a range of values to deselect/select.

`function(x)` is called as anonymous function using which you can apply your own functions to every row of the data frame.

`rollmean` does not handle `NA` values. From the document of `?rollmean`

> The default method of rollmean does not handle inputs that contain NAs. In such cases, use rollapply instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I have two questions

Comment: Thank you.  I have two questions

1. If I had more than one column to remove at the start to do the apply function (player and Tm) how do you do that?  I see that the q[-1] removes the one, but I am unclear on why other numbers do what they do.

2. can you explain why the "function(x)" is needed?  I have seen it used a couple of times but I don't understand what it is doing.

Comment: Also I just noticed that this does not skip over the NA values, is that possible as well?  thanks again.

Comment: @runnin4tay5000 I have updated the post with the answers to your questions. Have a look.